# Retrieve vertex of a graph based on values and attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I am creating a graph with vertices and edges using networkx in python.

```
G=add_edge(vertex1,vertex2)
```

`vertex1` and `vertex2` are integers i.e.

```
G=add_edge(4,3),
G=add_edge(2,3)
etc..
```

Since, in python, if we just give the edge list, it creates the vertex and create the edges between the specified vertexes.

Now I need to add an attribute to the vertices of the graph, i.e. I want to basically separate the vertices into groups based on the attribute.

Hence, I can do

```
G.node[your_vertex]['attribute'] = value
```

to add an attribute to the already created graph `G`.

Since there can be many different attributes and different values, how do I retrieve the vertex

1. By its value
2. By its attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over the nodes and see which ones:

1. have some value for the attribute (i.e. the attribute is a key in the dictionary of attributes); or,
2. have the particular value you desire for the attribute.

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(4, 3)
>>> G.add_edge(2, 3)
>>> G.add_edge(2, 5)
>>> G.node[2]['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> G.node[3]['foo'] = 'qux'
>>> attribute = 'foo' # the attribute you want
>>> value = 'bar' # the value you want for that attribute
>>> [n for n in G.node if attribute in G.node[n].keys()]
[2, 3]
>>> [n for n in G.node if G.node[n].get(attribute) == value]
[2]
```

If you need to do a lot of these lookups, this will probably not be very fast - you may want to consider building some sort of index of nodes that have the attributes/values you're interested in, assuming that a node's attributes/values don't change very often.